# Present UIViewController and pass back data to presenting view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have an app that requires you to select data in a modal `UIViewController` at multiple locations in the app. Imagine that like this: you want to see if a restaurant has any available tables -> a modal `UIViewController` pops up where you select a restaurant in a list, which dismisses it and communicates the data back to the presenting view. You want to see related restaurants -> a modal `UIViewController` pops up where you select a restaurant in a list, which dismisses it and communicates the data back to the presenting view. Etc.

Now, I could do this by setting `RestaurantViewController.delegate = self` in the presenting view. I could then call something like `[delegate pickedRestaurant:restaurant];`, but I don't like how ungeneric that is.

Is there any other way to present a `UIViewController` with a data callback?

Comment: What do you mean that the delegate pattern is "ungeneric"? That is exactly what the pattern is designed for, to ensure the presented view controller is only concerned with its own implementation; delegates can then respond to that callback as needed without affecting the responsibilities of the child controller.

Comment: Well, @Stuart what I meant was that I need to implement the same code multiple times. But after doing some extended research, I agree that this is the best option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `delegate` design pattern is useful when you want to pass data back to the presenting `UIViewController` as you have pointed out in your question. If you do not want to go down the delegation design pattern then perhaps you can use `NSNotificationCenter`? It does not hold much memory and it triggers an app-wide broadcast which can be picked up by an NSObserver which you can place in your presenting `UIViewController` (that is assuming that your presenting `UIViewController` is still in memory. For example, the codes can look something along the lines of this:

**ViewControllerA.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
 super.viewDidLoad()
 let notifCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
 notifCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewControllerA.methodToTrigger), name: "pickedRestaurantNoti", object: nil)
}

func methodToTrigger(notification:NSNotification){

    let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String!> = notification.userInfo as Dictionary<String,String!>
    let pickedRestaurantFromB = userInfo["pickedRestaurant"]
    // pickedRestaurantFromB should have the value of "Restaurant 1"
    // handle that value now that you have gotten it

}
```

**ViewControllerB.swift**

```
func someMethod(){
 let notifCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
 notifCenter.postNotificationName("pickedRestaurantNoti",
                        object:nil,
                        userInfo:["pickedRestaurant":"Restaurant 1"])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume there are two vc A and B.

Add property in B.h as

```
@property A *aobjet
```

and property in A.h as

```
@property NSString *str;
```

when you present B call like this from A.m

```
B *b = [B alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:B animated:YES completion:^{
  b.aobject = self;

}];
```

then set property of A before pop from B.m for example string,

```
self.aobject.str = @"your data";
 [[self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];
```

Please avoid syntax mistakes if any because i have typed it here.!